# Как использовать не приобщенную к каталогам память Linux

Tags: linux, память, lvm, disk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется 80ГБ на sda3. 40ГБ занимает раздел vg-ubuntu--lv под / который полностью переполнен.

Остальная память на sda3 (тоже примерно 40) свободна и каталогом не используется (как я это понимаю). Я хочу воспользоваться этими оставшимися незанятыми ГБ.

По сути без разницы будет это новый каталог или расширение существующего. Мне просто нужна эта память. Требуется установка тяжелого ПО.

Подскажите, как мне лучше решить эту задачу.

Comment: В разделе / хранятся важные файлы, которые не должны пострадать.

Comment: дык, просто увеличь корень `lvresize /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv -r -L +10G` ЗЫ:  и на будущее, пость текст, а не картинки…

Comment: Все так просто.. Спасибо это мне помогло!